# Moved a folder to /dev. Folder has disappeared after rebooting

Tags: files, directory, root

As the title says, I can't find the folder there now. I looked it up and /dev is some form of device files, so I'm not sure whether the folder I moved there should disappear after rebooting or not?

Answer (score 2):

`/dev` is a virtual file system that doesn't exist on your hard disk but only in RAM.

It's created at every system startup and all changes and copied files there are lost when you shut down your system.